# How to output a value of a function with parameters onclick in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

I have a function that outputs a random number and I want to output the value below the button when it's clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
  <input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="genRand()">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function genRand(min, max, decimalPlaces) {  
  var rand = Math.random()*(max-min) + min;
  var power = Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces);
  return Math.floor(rand*power) / power;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If I want the rest of the page to stay when the button is clicked I believe I need to use innerhtml, but I'm having no luck working out how to incorporate it into the code.

I'm new to html and javascript, so any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
function genRand(min, max, decimalPlaces) {  
  var rand = Math.random()*(max-min) + min;
  var power = Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces);
  var result = Math.floor(rand*power) / power;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="genRand(0,10,2)">
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: It works, but I'm not quite sure why, so I guess I'll have to study innerhtml more. Thank you so much for the quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass values when you are calling the function.

```
<input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="genRand('Minimum Value', 'Maximum Value','Decimal Places')">
```

For Eg:

```
<input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="genRand(1,10,2)">
```

Comment: I tried that (forgot to include it here), but it didn't work

Comment: You need to print the output or show it in alert box, otherwise you won't notice anything.
For Eg:
<input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="alert(genRand(1,10,2));">